# Appropriate way to organize tests given new hardware features

Tags: test-management, hardware, test-infrastructure

I work with network/server infrastructure. On of our products (a server host) now supports wire connections with SFP(+) modules for copper (RJ45) and fiber (previously only RJ45).

The tests for our product are almost exclusively centered around performance and the features of the software used on the server. There are no explicit mentions of the cables etc. The few "hardware" tests revolve arund e.g. redundancy (plug one cable out, verify that the other is used for data etc.).

Now that we are introducing the concept of SFP modules and/or fiber, it will be relevant to write up new tests. But other than adding performance/throughput/load tests, verifying speeds, what other tests should be added?

Furthermore, and most importantly, how much should the current tests be refactored? Is it appropriate to just add a set of new test cases labeled/structured as e.g. "SFP tests", without modifying any of the old test cases? Or should I instead modify all (relevant) existing test cases to accommodate for the new hardware?

To make it more general:
Given a large test database, mostly focused on software performance, how to properly restructure the test database to accommodate for hardware changes?